# How to implement multi-threading into a Python WSGI server

Tags: python, concurrency, webserver

Just to clarify up front that this is just a learning project and I have no intention of using this in production. There are several very good Python application servers out there already. But I am trying to learn more about concurrency, so I set out to write one of the things (I thought) I knew.

Also, because I wanted to "closer to the metal" so I started out with just Socket and want to keep it that way.

Below is the important parts of what I have so far. self.iq is a Queue object (inbound_queue) which then does nothing really, but puts the request (which includes the socket object) into the outbound_queue and then a Consumer object takes the request from the outbound_queue and passes it to the ResponseHandler. This seems to work fine with just me hitting it but I am concerned that I am opening myself up to a race condition with a naive implementation. Specifically assigning things to the ServerClass object that are request specific.

So the question is: Is there a better way to do this, or does my Queue usage prevent two threads from picking up and operating on the same object? Should I be encapsulating things like the WSGI environment stuff into a separate object that can be also passed into the queue? Doing stuff like that gets tricky in trying to write a server that is WSGI compliant because of the need to pass in callback functions.

```
class Consumer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, out_queue, server):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.out_queue = out_queue
        self.server = server

    def run(self):
        while True:
        item = self.out_queue.get()
        self.server.ResponseHandler(self.server, item)
        self.out_queue.task_done()

class QueueConsumerServer(object):

    methods_allowed = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'options', 'upgrade']

    def __init__(self, host, port, application):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.application = application
        self.iq = Queue.Queue()
        self.oq = Queue.Queue()

        self.socket = socket.socket()
        self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
        #<snip of lots of assigning stuff to environ>
        self.environ = environ
        headers_set = []
        headers_sent = []
        for i in xrange(3):
            thr = Producer(self.iq, self.oq)
            thr.daemon = True
            thr.start()

        for i in xrange(3):
            thr = Consumer(self.oq, self)
            thr.daemon = True
            thr.start()


    def handle_request(self):
        self.socket.listen(1)
        try:
            while True:
                cli, addr = self.socket.accept()
                data = cli.recv(1024)
                request_data = self.parse_request_data(data)
                req.path = request_data[1]
                req.cli = cli
                self.iq.put(req)
                return
        except Exception, ex:
            print 'e', ex,
            sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            sys.stdout.flush()
            self.socket.close()
```

Comment: not true. a closer to the metal wsgi implementation is actually faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python queues are [thread safe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), so there is no race in your code as written.

Regarding a better way to approach this, your code will probably hit the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) before too long. I would suggest looking to into [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the multiprocessing module. This was a learning exercise, so I am running through all of the different types of concurrency. Thread, Multiprocessing, Greenlets, Coroutines, etc.

Comment: Good stuff. It's worth bearing in mind that threads in python have inferior performance characteristics to threads in other languages (e.g. c++, java), due to the GIL. They are still useful for IO multiplexing, but you're going to need to use processes if you want to exploit multiple cores in vanilla python.

Comment: Understood. I can't imagine using this for doing anything except maybe a static file server where you are IO-bound. But as I study threading/concurrency, web servers tend to be my "hello world". Which is actually all this server serves right now. Thanks for the quick answer.